# To check if an element is present in a string array using "Regex" in c#

Tags: c#, regex

Help me guys to complete the code using Regex. I'm new to learn c#.

Create a C# program to complete the following task using Regular Expressions

i. Create a string variable 'Myinput' and read the value from user

ii. Check whether the given values are matching with the following

1. Cappuccino
2. Tea
3. Milk
4. Espresso

iii. If any other values except the above, the program need to throw an error

message

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegularExpression
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the user choice input");
            string Myinput = Console.ReadLine();

            string[] arrayy = new string[4] { "Cappucino", "Tea", "Milk", "Espresso" };
            MyChoice obj = new MyChoice();
            bool ans = obj.MyChoiceContains(Myinput, arrayy);

            Console.WriteLine(ans);
            Console.ReadKey();

            /// i. Create a string variable 'Myinput' and read the value from user. 
            /// ii. Check whether the given values are matching with the following 
            ///     1.Cappuccino 2. Tea 3. Milk 4. Espresso. 
            /// iii. If any other values except the above, the program need to throw the error 
            ///message.
            /// Display valid or invalid message here.
        }
    }
    public class MyChoice
    {
        public bool MyChoiceContains(string Userchoice, string[] myChoiceValues)
        {
            Userchoice = @"^[A-Za-z]$";

            Regex rg = new Regex(Userchoice);


            bool ans = true;
            foreach (string s in myChoiceValues)
            {
                ans = Regex.IsMatch(Userchoice, s);
            }
            return ans;

            }

        }
    }
/// <summary>
/// Create Class with Class name 'MyChoice'. 
/// </summary>


/// <summary>
/// Create a method with the name 'MyChoiceContains'.
/// <param name="Userchoice"></param><type>string</type>
/// <param name="myChoiceValues"></param><type>string[]</type>
/// <returns>bool</returns>return "true" if valid else return "false".
/// Note: Please dont use Console.WriteLine() and Console.ReadLine() in this method.
/// </summary>
```

Comment: I don't see how regular expressions relate to your question. Do you mean that the user should be able to input a regular expression and all matching elements should be printed?

Comment: @Llama Exactly.

Comment: In that case, what is the issue you're facing (other than that you've hardcoded the values in `MyChoiceContains`)? Is your issue that you're always exiting the loop on the first item rather than also checking subequent items in the case that the first one is valid?

Comment: I need to check that whether the input string which is in the Regex format, matches with any one of the array elements. If yes then return true else return false.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments you have stated that the user will input a regular expression, and that you want to check if the regular expression matches on any of the elements in the array. You can either do this manually:

```cs
foreach (string s in myChoiceValues)
{
    if (rg.IsMatch(s))
        return true;
}   
return false;
```

I've moved the `return false;` outside so that you don't `return false;` when the first item doesn't match.

Alternatively, you can do this using the LINQ extension methods. You'll need to ensure you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file.

```cs
return myChoiceValues.Any(v => rg.IsMatch(v));
// or simply: return myChoiceValues.Any(rg.IsMatch);
```

You might also need to rewrite your hardcoded test expression (`^[A-Za-z]$`) as this currently requires a single character between the start and end of the string (i.e. the matched string should be a single character). Perhaps you meant:

```regex
^[A-Za-z]+$
```

The `+` means it will match 1 or more characters matching from the `[A-Za-z]` set.

Comment: @Rajesh Is it not because of the problem I outlined in the last part of my answer? [Example](https://rextester.com/GQTM67287)

Comment: I'm getting true if I enter other than these four elements in the array. So what's the error here?

Comment: @RAJESHVARMAR I think you might want to read up on what regular expressions do. You seem to be struggling with that. `^[A-Za-z]+$` ensures that all characters in the string are from the set `A-Za-z`. That's all. That's what you have described in your question. [Example](https://regex101.com/r/OUATVe/1)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for solution in my case (where I have nullable strings) and I created sth like below:

```
var result = Regex.Matches(anyData.field_from_json.ValidationException(), @"\d*")
.Where(r => r.Length > 3)
.First()
.Value;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  string pattern = @"(Cappuccino | Tea | Milk | Espresso)";
  string input = "text";
  Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  if (m.Success) 
  {
     // matched
  }
  else
  {
     // not matched
  }
```

[Ressource](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=net-5.0)